# Fetching Images and other Details in Index page based on two dropdown selected value?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am new to php.I have a problem with a dropdown list. Let me explain it in little detail.I have a database that contains Two Tables: firstCata and subCata. The table subCata references firstCata ID. Now in my index.php page I have a form with 2 drop downs. First is for firstCata and second shows values based on first from my database. All this I had done using Ajax.Code is Below. Problem is that using ajax I had displayed a second drop down on  tag in index.php. How can I show other details of subCata in index.php Page?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSubCata(str)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getSunCata.php?q="+str.value,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<select onchange='getSubCata(this)'>
<?php 
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM firstCata") or die(mysql_error());
while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $rec['firstCata_id'];?>"><?php echo $rec['firstCata_name'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

and my getSunCata.php code is like

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('mainCata') or die(mysql_error());

?>
<select>
<?php
$id=$_GET['q'];
echo $id;
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcata where firstCata_id=$id") or die(mysql_error());
while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo $rec['subCata_name'];
?>
 <option id="a"value="echo $rec['subCata_id'];">
    <?php echo $rec['subCata_name']; ?>
</option>
    <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you need to print all subCata data in 2-nd select.
So why you need ajax for that if you want all subCata values displayed too?
Here is my solution:

```
// MySQL query
$sql = '
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        firstCata
    JOIN
        subCata
    ON
        firstCata_id = subCata_id';
```

Template html script using jQuery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var selects_pair = $('select[name="firstCata"], select[name="subCata"]')
    selects_pair.change(function(){
        // get selected id
        var selected_id = $(':selected', this).val();
        // set another selectd corresponding value
        $('[value="' + selected_id + '"]', selects_pair.not(this)).attr("selected", "selected");
    });
});
</script>
```

Template html markup

```
// looping through the data like this, add foreach cycle as you want

<select name="firstCata">
    <option value="<?php echo $rec['firstCata_id'];?>"><?php echo $rec['firstCata_name'];?></option>
</select>

<select name="subCata">
    <option value="<?php echo $rec['subCata_id'];?>"><?php echo $rec['subCata_name'];?></option>
</select>
```